# Java get NULL value from getUsername(); (diffrent class files)

Tags: java, file, class, null

So i am practising my java skills and after 2.5hrs of trying and thinking without asking help i am kinda lost...

The problem is in the class Welcome i am setting a username and role. 
but in the terminal i want to use the username via the Getter but it comes out null

check for classes below

Welcome class:

```
public class Welcome {

    public static void welcome(){
        Player m = new Player();
        String user;
        String roletype;
        Float startersmoney;
        // welcome msg
        System.out.println("Welcome to 'Roots'.");

        //enter your desired username
        System.out.println("Enter your alias : ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Ruler.ruler();
        user = scanner.nextLine();
        m.setUsername(user);
        // returns username

        System.out.println("Your alias is now set to : " + m.getUsername());
        // are you a hacker?
        System.out.println("What are you? a 'hacker' or ? ");
        Ruler.ruler();
        roletype = scanner.nextLine();
        m.setRole(roletype);
        m.setCurrency(250.00);
        //checks user input. and gives output
        if (m.getRole().equalsIgnoreCase("hacker")) {
            System.out.println("So you are a : " + m.getRole().toLowerCase());
        } else {
            System.out.println("hahahaha... NOOOOB!!!\n only hackers are allowed to play 'Roots'..");
        }
        System.out.println("Okay lets get started. hint : 'help' ");
        Ruler.ruler();
        Terminal.terminal();
    }
```

Ruler Class

```
  public class Ruler {

    // for input markup '@root:~ > ' <- feels like terminal :D
    public static void ruler(){
        Player r = new Player();
        System.out.print(r.getUsername() + "@root:~ > ");
    }
}
```

Player class

```
public class Player {

    //variables
    private String username;
    private String role;
    private double currency;

    //setters
    public void setUsername(String value)   {   this.username = value;      }
    public void setRole(String role)        {   this.role = role;           }
    public void setCurrency(Double currency){   this.currency = currency;   }

    //getters
    public String getUsername() {   return this.username;        }
    public String getRole()     {   return this.role;            }
    public Double getCurrency() {   return this.currency;        }

}
```

Comment: You're creating a new instance of Player in the Ruler class, which doesn't have a username. You should probably pass the Player to the Ruler class

Comment: hmm okay how is this fixable?

Comment: Don't create a new instance where you want to reuse a value. Remove the static requirement on Ruler#rulrer and pass the instance of Player to it I instead. This is the same concept you have for your setters

Comment: MadProgrammer is i don't have them static my program won't run and with them i still get Nulls....

Comment: `public static void ruler(){` looks pretty static to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is common -- that of creating a new instance of an object and expecting it to magically acquire the state of other objects of the same class. This is not how Java works.

Look at how many times you see `new Player()` in your code. Each time you see it, you're doing just that, creating a **new** Player object, one distinct from all others. So setting the state of one will have no effect on the other one whose state you're checking.

Solution: by passing references, check the state of the previously created Player object only. Don't create a new one in your listener code.

So:

```
public class Ruler {
   private Player player;

   public Ruler(Player player) {
      this.player = player;
   }

    // **** this shouldn't be static!
    public void checkState(){
        // Player r = new Player();
        // System.out.print(r.getUsername() + "@root:~ > ");
        System.out.print(player.getUsername() + "@root:~ > ");
    }
}
```

then in

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Player player = new Player();
    Ruler ruler = new Ruler(player);

    // now call player and ruler methods as desired
}
```

---

**Edit**
You state:

> .btw it has to be static otherwise i cant use it.... for some reason..

NO! Then you're fixing the **wrong** thing. The key is to fix your code so that **it doesn't have to be static**.

---

> look here : /home/stefano/intelliJ_Projects/Roots/src/com/stefano/Welcome.java Error:(32, 14) java: non-static method ruler() cannot be referenced from a static context Error:(44, 14) java: non-static method ruler() cannot be referenced from a static context Error:(45, 17) java: non-static method terminal() cannot be referenced from a static context

Again, as my code shows, get rid of the static ruler method and instead use only a non-static method. The Ruler class must have state, must have non-static variables, and so you should call instance methods on objects of the class, not static methods. You're doing things backwards, I'm afraid.

Comment: ahh i see.. how can i fix this?

Comment: @StefanoGroenland: by passing references, check the state of the previously created Player object only. Don't create a new one in your listener code.

Comment: trying now ! hold on :D

Comment: look here :
/home/stefano/intelliJ_Projects/Roots/src/com/stefano/Welcome.java
Error:(32, 14) java: non-static method ruler() cannot be referenced from a static context
Error:(44, 14) java: non-static method ruler() cannot be referenced from a static context
Error:(45, 17) java: non-static method terminal() cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: because my main where everything happens is // function where everything happens!
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Welcome.welcome();
        Terminal.terminal();
    }

Comment: @StefanoGroenland: You're fixing things backwards. The solution is not to make stuff static but to fix your code so that you don't need static methods or fields. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize the username of the player before displaying it.  For example, after creating a new player, set the value of the username.

```
public class Ruler {

    // for input markup '@root:~ > ' <- feels like terminal :D
    public static void ruler(String username){
        Player r = new Player();
        r.setUserName(username); // Here you can give it a value

        System.out.print(r.getUsername() + "@root:~ > ");
    }
}
```

In your Welcome class

```
public class Welcome {

    public static void welcome(){
        ....

        //enter your desired username
        System.out.println("Enter your alias : ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        user = scanner.nextLine();
        Ruler.ruler(user);
        ...

}
```

And Ruler should have a Player attribute

```
public class Ruler {
   private Player player;
   ...
}
```

Comment: the username is set in another file :)

Comment: @StefanoGroenland So?

Comment: Indeed, so? ... and 1+

Comment: i mis interpreted your sentence im sorry !